# How can I get jVisualVM to display longer timeframes?

Tags: monitoring, jvisualvm

I am trying to use jVisualVM to monitor the long-term heap use of a few applications I am developing. Currently it only shows the past hour under the "Monitor" tab. Is there any way I can view a longer timeframe, and even better, any way I can view it from start to end?

If this can't be done in jVisualVM, are there any suggestions on alternatives?

Comment: I found an answer. Go to Tools -> Options, and change Charts Cache to something bigger (say their max, 99,999 minutes ~70 days). If anyone has a better solution or alternative, please post it!

Comment: I take back what I said, that didn't work...

Comment: It would only last an hour in monitor. But I downloaded the Tracer plugins and now I can see the entire weekend

Comment: If you go to Tools -> Options, and change Charts Cache, it will change the settings for Monitor tab. This is what I had in mind when I wrote 'it works for me' above.

Comment: It's strange, it's worked for me now too! But the Tracer plugins give much nicer zoom capabilities and other features that I think it's my preferred solution

Comment: Ok. I am glad that it works. I am also glad that you find Tracer plugin useful.